# create table from nested php foreach loops

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple html table from nested foreach loops. Actual data will be stored in my database.
I want a table will look like:

```
---------------------
1  |  A  |  red     |
---------------------
2  |  B  |  blue    |
---------------------
3  |  C  |  yellow  |
---------------------
4  |  D  |  orange  |
---------------------


$values1 = "1,2,3,4";
$values2 = "A,B,C,D";
$values3 = "red,blue,yellow,orange";

$var1 = explode(',', $values1);
$var2 = explode(',', $values2);
$var3 = explode(',', $values3);

echo '<table>';

    foreach ($var1 as $row1) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$row1.'</td>';

        foreach ($var2 as $row2) {
            echo '<td>'.$row2.'</td>';
        }
        foreach ($var3 as $row3) {
            echo '<td>'.$row3.'</td>';
        }
        echo '</tr>';
    }

echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works :

```
<?php
$values1 = "1,2,3,4";
$values2 = "A,B,C,D";
$values3 = "red,blue,yellow,orange";

$var1 = explode(',', $values1);
$var2 = explode(',', $values2);
$var3 = explode(',', $values3);

echo '<table border="1">';
for($i = 0; $i < count($var1); $i++){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$var1[$i].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$var2[$i].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$var3[$i].'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}


echo '</table>';
```

Comment: fico stole this from ME.  I even had `border="1"`

Comment: haha where is your answer ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this could help you. Defining your values directly as arrays, and representing them with a foreach loop. It's more like the way mysql_fetch_array represents the records obtained from the database.

```
$values   = [];
$values[] = [1, "A", "red"];
$values[] = [2, "B", "blue"];
$values[] = [3, "C", "yellow"];
$values[] = [4, "D", "orange"];

echo '<table>';
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$value[0].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$value[1].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$value[2].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: well, you changed OP's input data (arrays)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `$var1` as "base" array, could be handy to check if other arrays also contain the same indexes (same length as `$var1`) to avoid PHP warnings.

```
foreach ($var1 as $key => $value) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.(isset($var2[$key]) ? $var2[$key] : '').'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.(isset($var3[$key]) ? $var3[$key] : '').'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```